# custom folder location using environment variables example %appdata%

Tags: variables, windows-7, batch-file, cmd, environment

what I wish to do is set up a custom folder(s) so run automated batches without typing out very long paths for example **%appdata%** for "C:\Users\%user%\Appdata\roaming".

So if I wanted to create a folder in lets say "C:\Users\%user%\randomfolder\randomfolder2\ect\ect" and I wanted to make a environment variable %randomfolder% to access via batch file.

Jordan Dap

Answer (score 2):

To *define* the variable:

```
set randomfolder=C:\Users\%user%\randomfolder\randomfolder2\ect\ect
```

To *use* the variable, for example:

```
cd %randomfolder%
```

Comment: this was semi useful and I am grateful for the quick response but by environment variable I meant set it before the window opens for example using the windows users environment variables without setting them via cmd or batch

Comment: Then define it via Control Panel> System> Advanced tab> Environment Variables> and enter a New variable either for the current user or the whole System. HOWEVER, you must be aware that incorrect changes made to other variables this way may corrupt your system! BE CAREFUL!

Comment: If this answer/comment was useful to you, may I ask you to select it as the right answer to your question? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To `SET`  from a .BAT file an environment variable **permanent**, you need to use the console registry tool `REG`, and access it as a variable:

1. either the current user permanent environment in the key `HKCU\Environment`
2. or in the machine environment in the key `"HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"`

Read `REG /?` and try ...

```
 REG ADD HKCU\Environment /v randomfolder /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "C:\Users\%user%\randomfolder\etc"
```